# Why does this print out spospo?

Tags: python

```
>>> print("loops"[- 1:1:- 1]*2)
spospo
>>>
```

Why wouldn't the output be `slssls`?

Comment: Because of the slicing notation. It's `[start:end:step]`, where negative indices count from the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"loops"[-1:1:-1]
```

Let’s check how [slicing works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common):

> `s[i:j:k]` – slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k`
>
> If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string: `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that `-0` is still `0`.
>
> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k` is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when `j` is reached (but never including `j`). If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`. If `i` or `j` are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of `k`). Note, `k` cannot be zero. If `k` is `None`, it is treated like `1`.

So `[-1:1:-1]` means `i = -1`, `j = 1`, `k = -1`.

`i` is negative, so `i = -1` means that `i = len(s) + (-1) = len(s) - 1`. `len(s)` is `5`, so we get the following slice: `"loops"[4:1:-1]`.

As per above definition, we now the the items with the following indexes: `4`, `4 - 1 = 3`, `4 - 2 = 2`. We stop at `4 - 3 = 1` because that is our end, and we don’t include that.

So the result are indexes `4, 3, 2`, which is `'spo'`.

Finally, that string is multiplied by `2` which repeats it once: `'spospo'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!